# How to apply Google App Script to a Sheets that contains a certain value in certain place?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to be selective with applying conditional formatting to Google Sheets. For example, if I were looking to apply it to all sheets I would do something like this

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3");
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenNumberBetween(1, 10)
      .setBackground("#FF0000")
      .setRanges([range])
      .build();
   var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
   rules.push(rule);
   sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

I want to apply said rules ONLY for sheets that have "`Type: ABC`" located in cell "`A1`"

How can this be done please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like like this:

```
function myfunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts = ss.getSheets().filter(s => sh.getRange('A1').getValue() == "Type: ABC");
  shts.forEach(sheet => {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3");
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenNumberBetween(1, 10)
      .setBackground("#FF0000")
      .setRanges([range])
      .build();
    var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
    rules.push(rule);
    sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  });
```